# The probability of getting an odd sum

Tags: statistics

[image]

Mu turn:

The number of even numbers =$3$ , the number of odd numbers = $5$

So the possibilities to get an odd sum are

EEO , EOE , OEE , OOO
Where E means even , O means odd then the probability is
$\frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{7}\times \frac{5}{6})\times 3 + \frac{5}{8} \times \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{3}{6} = \frac{25}{56}$

Is this correct ? I

Comment: looks fineeeeee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment:**

A simulation of a million such draws of three (without
replacement) from the bag should give an answer correct
to about three decimal places. Your answer is $25/56 =
0.4464286.$ The simulated answer is $0.4459 \pm 0.0010.$
So your answer looks good.

```
set.seed(2011)
bag = c(1,1,2,4,4,5,5,5)
jona = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(bag, 3)))
mean((jona/2) != round(jona/2))
[1] 0.445945     # aprx P(Odd)
2*sd((jona/2) != round(jona/2))/1000
[1] 0.0009941394 # aprx 95% margin of sim. error
25/56
[1] 0.4464286    # exact
```